# How to log errors in browser (error view) instead of blank screen in React

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

I have a React application which is not created with create-react-app. I would like to add a error handling functionality but I have no idea how:

When there is an error, instead of getting a blank page and errors in console, in development, **how do I enable this functionality in a React application**
where it shows the error stack in the browser?

Do I have to write the code for it or there is a react configuration that I can just enable or should I use a library to achieve this?

[image: React application, error stack in browser]

### EDIT:

Above image is what I want to see as an error report in my browser when there is an error. It is not an error I am trying to solve.

Comment: Please try https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html in your root component

Comment: Thank you @ViswanathLekshmanan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) . Add those in your Root Level to catch all errors inside that.